# Align textview to the actual bound of an image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I'm confused with a problem about ImageView alignment recently. We know that the width of ImageView is **NOT** exactly the width of the actual image (because sometimes the image is scaled). So how can I align a textview to the bound of **the actual image**, not the ImageView?

```
+----------------------------------------+
|            +--------------+            |
|  ImageView | Scaled Image |            |
|            +--------------+            |
+----------------------------------------+

                            | I want to align my textview to here

                                         | Not here
```

The following code doesn't meet my requirement, it always align the textview to the right of the **ImageView**, not the actual image:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/mypic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/mypic" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytext"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/mypic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to set scaletype to your imageview so that it always fits the imageview. i dont think you can set your textview according to the scaled image(it differs for images)

Comment: see `ImageView#getImageMatrix` and  `ImageView#getDrawable` methods, then read carefully `Matrix` API

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from your post is that you want to align the textview to the right of your imageview, you can do it like so:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/mypic"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/mypic" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/mytext"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/mypic" />
</RelativeLayout>
```